# TSQL Comparing Date ranges

Tags: sql-server-2008, datetime

DATA:

```
DECLARE @rundate datetime = GETDATE()

DECLARE @DatesTable TABLE (name varchar(200),STARTDATE datetime,ENDDATE datetime)
INSERT INTO @DatesTable VALUES('campaign1',GETDATE(),GETDATE()+10)

INSERT INTO @DatesTable
VALUES('campaign2',GETDATE()+11,GETDATE()+13)
```

For the above data I have 2 active campaigns running one after another.
For a given date (rundate) I need to select the one valid campaign for which the @rundate is applicable from the @DatesTable.

Basically the enddate to look at is depending on the next campaigns start date and figuring out for which campaign the @rundate is valid for and returning that result.

If no result is returned then the last campaign needs to be returned.

Comment: All your columns are `datetime`. Should we ignore the time component?

Comment: Yes - time is always going to be 00:00:00.000

Comment: If you need to know if a campaign recorded in table @@DatesTable is running on a specific date (which is put in the @@rundate variable)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have an easier time (no `CAST`) if everything is declared as `date` instead of `datetime`. Anyhow, give this a try:

```
;WITH
    cte AS
    (
        SELECT  name, STARTDATE, ENDDATE,
                rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ENDDATE DESC) 
        FROM    @DatesTable
        WHERE   CAST(STARTDATE AS date) <= CAST(@rundate AS date)
    )

SELECT  *
FROM    cte
WHERE   rn = 1
```

It selects all campaigns that started on or before `@rundate`, and rank them descendingly by `ENDDATE`. Finally it gets the latest campaign according to that order.